# Does Ubuntu support UPS out of the box?

Tags: ups

I have UPS that used to work fine on windows before (had some software installed though) and now is just connected to the PC without installing anything.
Well, the moment the electricity goes out the PC shutdowns instantly like there is no UPS connected at all.

So, do I need to install something generally to work or  my UPS might have hardware problem?

Comment: How about posting the UPS model and how you connected it? via USB/serial?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the software. All UPS continue to work without the USB/serial connection.

Depending on what model UPS you have, you may have to run different software. e.g. the powstatd package provides software for what it calls "dumb" UPS. gunpower and upsd are other packages which do similar things. You may have to figure out which works best for your needs.

Comment: So, I guess it's 100% hardware problem then? Is there any way to test that for sure?

Answer (score 0):

I know that APC UPS works straight out of the box without additional software,
Ubuntu since 10.04 (perhaps even earlier) to the latest 14.04 will detect the UPS automatically if it's connected by the USB cable.

Not sure if other brands are detected automatically.